# Get category_id of entry before loop?

Tags: categories, entry, gwcode-categories

I want to list out all posts based on the category_id of the current entry. But how can I get the category_id before the loop?

Basically, what I could do is this:

```
{exp:channel:entries channel"mychannel" category_id="2"}
 {title}
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

The problem is, I don't know the `category_id` at that point.
As of now, I'm doing a basic channel entries loop, and run an embedded template that I pass the `category_id` to. And that template lists out all the posts with that category set.

So using [gwcode_categories](http://gwcode.com/add-ons/gwcode-categories/documentation), I can get the category_id and pass that along with the embedded template, like this:

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="mychannel"}
    {embed="include/get_posts"  
    category="{exp:gwcode_categories entry_id="{entry_id}" last_only="yes" style="linear"}{cat_id}{/exp:gwcode_categories}"}
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

My categories are nested, so that's why I'm using last_only btw.

But, is there a plugin of some sort that I can use to get the category_id of the current entry before the loop? Like some sort of global dynamic variable?

Comment: Nevermind, I found this plugin called Low Seg2Cat which is just amazing. Did exactly what I needed, I just used '{last_segment_category_id}' in the initial channel entries loop and that's it! :) I am a happy camper :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just found the solution by using this free addon called [Low Seg2Cat](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/low-seg2cat) which just lets me get the category_id of the current uri and pass that along with the initial channel:entries loop. Like this:

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="mychannel" category="{last_segment_category_id}" dynamic="no"}
```

I spent hours making that embedded template thing to work. And now I don't even need it. Allthough I did learn that it's possible to accomplish amazing stuff by embedding templates, so I got that going for me, which is nice.